# Error:(50, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/google_maps_key')

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm making an Android program using Android Studio. After open Android Studio and Gradle process finished, I got

> Error:(50, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@string/google_maps_key')".

What is happening? This is the first time I got this error.

Comment: there is missing google map key check your  google_maps_api.xml in values folder

Comment: Hi Maheshwar Ligade, this program is new and there is no google_maps_api.xml when i search in folder where this program is located. Please help what is the solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In manifest check the meta        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your map key />

Comment: Hi Maheshwar Ligade, this is code of the meta : "<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />". Is this correct ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your code you are read the key from @string/google_maps_key, instead of that put the key directly

Answer (score 5):

Even though this question was a few years ago, I will add an answer for the benefit of others. You should see a file named /src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml (copied below), in that file there are instructions to generate and add maps key. Replace the field
YOUR_KEY_HERE with your key.

```
To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end:

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
    YOUR_KEY_HERE
</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Sync project with gradle files.